# Force an infinite scroll page to load several pages

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-chrome, web

There's a page that has infinite scroll and it loads the next page when you scroll to the bottom of the current page, like twitter and facebook.

I want to force the page to load several pages instead of just one every time I reach the bottom.

I see in chrome's console that something new pops up into the elements and then disappear almost immediately. I managed to capture some of that element before it disappeared: `<iframe class="hidden_elem" name="transport_frame_9" src="/ajax/pagelet/...`
, The number in `transport_frame_9` increases on every load.

Also I tried to look in the `<script>` tags of the page for clues but couldn't find anything useful.

Is it even possible to invoke this script to load several pages? Or maybe there's a way to fool the page to think I reached the bottom several times? Like setting a some `scrolledToBottom` property to true?

Comment: Do you have a link so we can look? You should be able to call the function that does the page loading

Comment: @Omnisite it's facebook.

Comment: Well, in your console, you can do window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight); and that skips to the bottom of the page and then forces the next part to load.

Comment: And if you want to skip alot, you can first do window.scrollTo(0,10000); and then window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);

Comment: @Omnisite nice, it works great. Thank you.

Comment: @Omnisite do you know if it's possible to place it in a loop? When I try to do it even with sleep it scrolls to the bottom only once.

Comment: setInterval(function(){ window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight); }, 1000);
And then maybe have a counter and break the interval after x times